# thinking_shpinx, sphinx and MacOS X 10.6.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, sphinx, rvm, thinking-sphinx

After installing **thinking_sphinx** (http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts), and **Sphinx** (via brew - v.0.9.9-release (r2117) or via latest sources) and setting up ts in **Rails3** (Ruby via RVM: ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ], **rails 3.0.7**) app like:

```
  define_index do
    indexes :name
  end
```

and executing **rake ts:start** or **rake ts:index**, i permanently get:

```
ruby: invalid option -/  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
```

What the problem?

Comment: Never seen this one before... is there a stack trace?

Comment: No stack trace. It seems it was kinda local issue because of mystical SOMETHING.

Comment: Try a different patch level of Thinking Sphinx perhaps.